# When can Proguard optimize enums out?

Tags: proguard, android-proguard

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/optimizations says

> class/unboxing/enum
>
> Simplifies enum types to integer constants, whenever possible.

But the obvious question is, when is it possible? I assume the enum must not have fields/methods? Does it apply only to local variables or to method arguments as well?

In particular, if I have a enum with a field and a getter for this field, I could convert it to a static method switching on the enum; will this enable the optimization?

Comment: Did you ever find out when it changes enums to ints? For me they never change to ints. (I check the decompiled code)

Comment: @ThomasVos No, I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

### Optimization

Your assumption is correct, for the Proguard to optimize an `enum`, that `enum` should not have methods and associated values(fields). Proguard converts these simple enums to ints so, you get the type-safety of the enums at compile-time and the performance of ints at runtime.

It applies both to variables as well as method arguments.

So for your case where you have a field in an `enum`, the optimization won't apply.

[Jake Wharton](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7so7ne/you_should_strictly_avoid_using_enums_on_android/dt6aqki/) who worked for the Android team and [others](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7so7ne/you_should_strictly_avoid_using_enums_on_android/dt6awln/) have discussed enum optimization in this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7so7ne/you_should_strictly_avoid_using_enums_on_android/).

---

### Proguard Settings

The Proguard settings should look like following:

```
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Note the inclusion of the `proguard-android-optimize.txt` file and not the `proguard-android.txt` file.

[ProguardEnumIntDefTest](https://github.com/maxim-pandra/ProguardEnumIntDefTest) is a sample project on Github that tries to find out if Proguard converts enums into ints.

---